# Store IIS logs in Windows Azure

Tags: iis, azure, logging

I need to persist all IIS logs automatically in Azure storage, how to enable it?

I see that there are different properties in `DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration` class, e.g. DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs, Logs, Directories, etc. Which of the above is responsible for the IIS logs? What blob/table are the logs stored to?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240588/retrieving-iis-logs-from-azure

Comment: @serb: I looked at that question and it is not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under [Directory Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg593185.aspx), you have two options.. IIS Logs and Failed RequestLogs.

Here's a snippet from the diagnostic schema definition that outlines these options:

```xml
   <Directories bufferQuotaInMB="1024" 
  scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">

  <!-- These three elements specify the special directories 
       that are set up for the log types -->
  <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />
  <FailedRequestLogs container="wad-frq" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />
  <IISLogs container="wad-iis" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />

  <!-- For regular directories the DataSources element is used -->
  <DataSources>
     <DirectoryConfiguration container="wad-panther" directoryQuotaInMB="128">
        <!-- Absolute specifies an absolute path with optional environment expansion -->
        <Absolute expandEnvironment="true" path="%SystemRoot%\system32\sysprep\Panther" />
     </DirectoryConfiguration>
     <DirectoryConfiguration container="wad-custom" directoryQuotaInMB="128">
        <!-- LocalResource specifies a path relative to a local 
             resource defined in the service definition -->
        <LocalResource name="MyLoggingLocalResource" relativePath="logs" />
     </DirectoryConfiguration>
  </DataSources>
```

Comment: You can see the container name in the above entry.  That is the blob container for the files.

Comment: Thanks! Is IISLogs enabled by default, e.g. is it enough to set diagnosticConfiguration.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod in code, or do I need to update the config file?

Comment: Setting it in code will update the above config file. The sample is just a snippet of the xml that's stored in blob storage and leveraged by the Azure Diagnostics agent.